# Concatenate string rows up to length in oracle sql

Tags: sql, string, oracle, aggregate-functions

What I'm trying to achieve is concatenating strings up to a length of 10 with carriage return. If the row goes over length 10 then it should be added to the next concatenation row.

Example, having the following data set

[image]

```
SELECT '0123' col FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '45 67' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '89A' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'BC' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEFGHI' FROM DUAL
```

What I expect for the result

[image]

```
SELECT '0123
45 67' col FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '89A
BC' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEFGHI' FROM DUAL
```

I'm running oracle 12.1 and I don't want to do it in PLSQL due to performance reasons. I'm dealing with higher numbers.
I posted the simple example so it'll be easier. My end goal is to use listagg somehow where each row has a max of 4k chars

Comment: If you want carriage return, you need to concatenate CHR(13) to the strings.  rewarding splitting up a string and adding to the next row, I don't see how that can be done in straight SQL, but maybe someone smarter than me has a solution...  How many rows are you talking about, and how often do you need to do this?

Comment: What does "dealing with higher numbers" mean? thousands? millions?  How will you control the order of the data? You probably need more than just that one column to ensure the intended order. Is the source table indexed in any way?

Comment: **1.** What character (or characters) do you need to use for *newline*? `chr(10)` alone, which is standard in Oracle and is the line terminator in Unix? Or `chr(13) || chr(10)` as in DOS/Windows? Or something else? **2.** Do you need to add a newline at the end of the string too? **3.** What is your Oracle version? **4.** What should happen if an input string (in a single row) is LONGER than the limit already? Perhaps in your real use case (4000, not 10) that doesn't happen, but it may still be an issue **if** you must add a newline at the end (see earlier question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `match_recognize` solution, which requires Oracle 12.1 or higher. I make the following additional assumptions: the newline character is `chr(10)` as in Unix, the last row does NOT require a newline at the end, and all input row strings have length at most equal to the limit. (The limit, 10, can be changed to a bind variable.) I assume there is also an ordering column, which I called ORD.

```
with
  sample_data (ord, col) as (
    select 1, '0123'   from dual union all
    select 2, '45 67'  from dual union all
    select 3, '89A'    from dual union all
    select 4, 'BC'     from dual union all
    select 5, 'DEFGHI' from dual
  )
select rn, listagg(col, chr(10)) within group (order by ord) as fragment
from   sample_data
match_recognize (
  order by ord
  measures match_number() as rn
  all rows per match
  pattern (a+)
  define  a as sum(length(col)) + count(*) - 1 <= 10
)
group  by rn
order  by rn
;

   RN  FRAGMENT
-----  ------------
    1  0123
       45 67
    2  89A
       BC
    3  DEFGHI
```

Comment: Good assumptions. Thank you. I'll read more about match_recognize

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to group the rows and then `LISTAGG` to concatenate them:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG( col, CHR(10) ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY rn ) AS col
FROM   ( SELECT ROWNUM AS rn, col FROM table_name )
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER     BY rn
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS mno
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( short_strings* last_string )
  DEFINE short_strings AS NEXT(LENGTH(col)) <= 10 - SUM(LENGTH(col) + 1)
)
GROUP BY mno;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( col ) AS
SELECT '0123'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '45 67'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '89A'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BC'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEFGHI' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | COL    |
> | :----- |
> | 0123   |
> | 45 67  |
> | ------ |
> | 89A    |
> | BC     |
> | ------ |
> | DEFGHI |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b698e84785765145cc23f40e9a26b81d)*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group pairs of adjacent rows together, then you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows. Let me assume that you have such column and that is called `id`.

Then, you can use a recursive query. The idea is to traverse the dataset row by row, concatenating values until the length would exceed 10, at which point a new group must sart. The the outer query returns the latest row in each group:

```
with 
    data (id, col, rn) as (
        select t.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn 
        from mytable t
    ),
    cte (id, rn, newcol, grp) as (
        select id, rn, col, 1 from data d where rn = 1
        union all
        select d.id, d.rn, 
            case when length(c.newcol) + length(d.col) < 10
                then c.newcol || chr(13) || d.col
                else d.col
            end,
            case when length(c.newcol) + length(d.col) < 10
                then c.grp
                else d.rn
            end
        from cte c
        inner join data d on d.rn = c.rn + 1
    )
select max(newcol) as newcol 
from cte 
group by grp order by min(id)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7bbbff5d8cba4efd69fc6f7986e83751)**

Comment: It seems you didn't understand the question. The requirement is to stop adding new rows (as additional lines to a single string) when the total length of the string approaches the set limit. (10 in the example, but 4000 in the real-life use case). This has nothing to do with the number of input rows, or with dividing them into groups of two at a time. Nothing from your answer will help solve the problem the OP asked. Downvote from me, as "not helpful".

Comment: @mathguy: ah yes you are right, I misread the question. I changed the solution to offer a recursive query, which seems to do what is asked for here.

Comment: OK, I retracted my downvote. Your new solution will work in version 11.2 or higher (perhaps you can add that to your answer). Which means it is a good answer for 11.2 - for versions >= 12.1, `match_recognize` will be more efficient. (Also, the recursive query can be implemented in other db products, which don't have `match_recognize`.)